# Capture a jpeg image / image stream from a console program?

Tags: console, video, images, headless

I'm running a headless Raspberry Pi, and would like to convert the console/terminal output to a single jpeg or video stream.

For example: capture the output of `pbytop` every few seconds and stream it to a website using mjpeg (or through ffmpeg as a h264 stream).

I'm just stuck on the jpeg/video capturing part, streaming that media out of the pi to the website fine.

The closest I've managed to get is:

- ssh into pi
- start `tmux`
- start `pbytop` inside tmux
- ssh into pi from a second virtual terminal
- capture the tmux pane into a txt file:
- - `tmux capture-pane -J -p -t %0 > /tmp/pane-plain-text.txt`
- - `tmux capture-pane -e -J -p -t %0 > /tmp/pane-with-colors.txt`
- I can then `cat /tmp/pane-with-colours.txt` and it looks perfect, however that's still just a txt file with a bunch of color escape sequences in it, not an image.

[image: example showing capturing tmux to text]

Before I go down the "ascii to image" path can someone please point me in a better direction?

I feel like there's something I could do with a combination of `/dev/fb0` and extracting that to a stream using `ffmpeg -f fbdev -i /dev/fb0 etc...`

Comment: Would https://github.com/jiro4989/textimg help?

Comment: Oh @MarcusMüller that tool looks perfect for converting the captured tmux output to an image. Thank you!!! I'll use that if I cannot figure out a straight "terminal to image" solution.

Comment: Note that I've not tried that, it's just something I stumbled upon. But: I'm not sure what you mean with a "straight" terminal to image solution: there is no terminal attached, so there's nothing you could grab an image from. Tmux and your terminal emulator just see terminal control commands, and they keep a map of characters and states on the square character grid; nothing here works on pixels. And even if there were, the desirable solution would make you independent of rendering all tty states to framebuffers of some kind, just to get one every so and so many thousands frames.

Comment: If you are just trying to view a remote X11 screen in a web browser, a *vnc
server* on the pi can send the screen image in rfb protocol to your website
server and *vnc clients* like vncsnapshot can create a jpg from the stream. Or you
can use [novnc](http://kanaka.github.io/noVNC/) to view the stream via a
web socket in an html5 web page.

Answer (score 0):

For ascii to image use image magick or xwd to capture the content of a terminal window.

You can do this on your desktop or run it in a virtual X11 session (using Xvfb)

As you want to skip the text step
you could just run the original pbytop inside the virtual X11 and capture the images from there.

if you need to interract with xvfb you'll probably have to use xnee or xdotool to emulate input devices.

if you can use HTML instead of pictures,
another possibility is to use a2h to make HTML content.

Comment: Thanks for the list of tools (xwd xnee xdotool) I haven't heard of, I'll go and investigate each one. HTML might work too, but I'll try image first to avoid the concern of allow injecting remote HTML into a website.  I had hoped to avoid installing any X tools on the Pi, will see how we go.

Comment: you could use an iframe include the HMTL image as a separate file  if pasting it into the content is too tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The textimg tool would have been wonderful, [however it failed to handle certain characters correctly](https://github.com/jiro4989/textimg/issues/206). Hopefully I can figure it out as it would be the easiest option.

FWIW this is a solution I came up with: `tmux + python + imagemagick`

Start tmux on the raspberry pi via ssh, running the `bpytop` command that I want to "screenshot".

```
tmux new -dstelemetry 'bpytop'
```

Then capture the ansi output of this tmux window with:

```
tmux capture-pane -e -J -p -t telemetry > bpytop.ansi
```

Then convert the ansi file into svg with [this python tool](https://github.com/FHPythonUtils/AnsiToImg)

```
cat bpytop.ansi | ansitoimg --wide bpytop.svg
```

Then convert the svg to an image (cropping it slightly to remove white space)

```
convert bpytop.svg -crop 976x582+9+43 bpytop.jpg
```

### Screenshot showing terminal output, and the final produced jpeg

[image]